# What information about my computer can a browser send to a web server?

Tags: browser, privacy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hardware information about your PC's can gathered by websites/ISP's?](https://superuser.com/questions/206164/what-hardware-information-about-your-pcs-can-gathered-by-websites-isps)

I'm very curious about the limitations of the a capabilities of a browser to send the details of a computer's hardware and software details.

Here are some details point that I know about.

- OS,  Browser type, user IP address,  Resolution of the display

Some people say some sites can have the computer's network interface mac addresses. (like google adsense)

Answer (score 6):

Let me preface by saying that I work for a company that identifies devices based on things that can be observed in the browser.

Nobody (short of exploiting a security vulnerability) can get your mac address (EDIT: Unless you run native code from them e.g. as a plugin).

For a good overview of what can be seen, have a look at EFF's Panopticlick:

http://panopticlick.eff.org/

Comment: Unless you run ipv6, see [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/243669/how-to-avoid-exposing-my-mac-address-when-using-ipv6).